# $watch for element width inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to `$watch` my element's width inside a directive:

```
appDrct.directive('setWidth', function($interval) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function($scope, $elm, attr, ngModel) {

            $scope.$watch($elm.parent().width(), function() {
                console.log('Width changed');
            });
        }
     }
})
```

But it doesn't work...I know for a fact that my width changes (I tried with `$interval` to display the width and it changes)

Comment: how does you element width is changing everytime?

Comment: I use the following: http://codepen.io/Reklino/full/raRaXq/

Comment: you are expecting the watch to monitor changes on a primitive value ...that never changes. It will only return one value at the time the code is run.

Comment: So why when I use the interval I see the value changes? And how can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how you do it, you need to `$watch` the function expression:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
        return $element[0].style.width;
       }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log('Width changed');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13581/)